# when i try to input data in textfield the drop down values reset itself

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

i am getting the input fields data from api in the input field when i select values from the drop down it get reset when i try to input data in the textfield when the key board opens up it reset the data in the drop downs methods i have tried:
1- wrap the dropdown in builder and give it a global key ----// didnot work
2- make a separate widget for the listviewbuilder but didnot work
3- make a bool variable by defauld it is true when the screen is build in didchangedependencies funtion i give a false value to it when the value is true then it should build the listview builder otherwise it would build a sizedbox--- // did not work [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m061l.png)
when the keyboard is opened, the ListView.builder inside your CarAdOne widget rebuilds, causing the dropdown values to reset. This issue arises because the ListView.builder is rebuilding its items, and each time it does, it creates new instances of widgets, including the dropdowns.but when the build is called the values in the textfield is not getting reset only the dropdown values reset the same happens when i try to select values for radio buttons it rest other value

```
class CarAdOne extends StatefulWidget {
  const CarAdOne({super.key});

  @override
  State<CarAdOne> createState() => _CarAdOneState();
}

class _CarAdOneState extends State<CarAdOne> {
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    // context.read<AdsInputField>().makeSelectedList();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<AdsInputField>(context, listen: false)
        .getInputFields(categoryId: '135', pageId: '1');
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();

  getImages({required AdsInputFieldsModel data}) async {
    // Pick multiple images.
    final List<XFile> images = await picker.pickMultiImage();

    if (images.isNotEmpty) {
      data.attributes =
          images.map((e) => File(e.path)).toList() as List<Attribute>;
      setState(() {});
    }
    print(images);
    print(data.attributes);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    body: Consumer<AdsInputField>(builder: (context, value, child) {
    return value.isLoading
    ? const Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    )
    : value.adsInputFieldList.isEmpty
    ? Center(child: H2Bold(text: 'No Data'))
    Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.w),
    child: Column(
    children: [
    Expanded(
    child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: value.adsInputFieldList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    value.selectedValueList =
    value.adsInputFieldList.map((element) {
    if (element.categoryTypeId == '4') {
    // If the category id is '4', check if the value length should be attributes.length
    if (element.attributes.isEmpty) {
    // Handle the case where attributes is an empty list
    return AddSummaryModel(
    name: element.categoryFieldName,
    nameAr: element.categoryFieldNameArabic,
    value: [''],
    field: element.categoryTypeName,
    );
    } else {
    // Add values to selectedValueList with length equal to attributes.length
    return AddSummaryModel(
    

                                        nameAr: element.categoryFieldNameArabic,
                                        value: List.generate(
                                            element.attributes.length,
                                            (index) => 'false'),
                                        field: element.categoryTypeName,
                                      );
                                    }
                                  } else {
                                    // For categories other than '4', add values with an empty list
                                    return AddSummaryModel(
                                      name: element.categoryFieldName,
                                      nameAr: element.categoryFieldNameArabic,
                                      value: [''],
                                      field: element.categoryTypeName,
                                    );
                                  }
                                }).toList();
                                print('listviewbuilder called here');
                                final data = value.adsInputFieldList[index];

                                switch (data.categoryTypeId) {
                                  case "2":
                                    var dropdownList = data.attributes
                                        .map((e) => e.attributeName)
                                        .toSet()
                                        .toList();
                                    dropdownList.insert(0,
                                        data.categoryFieldName); // Add data.categoryFieldName at the 0th index
                                    return Padding(
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.h),
                                      child: SelectOptionForAd(
                                        index: index,
                                        dropdownName: data.categoryFieldName,
                                        dropDownValue: data.categoryFieldName,
                                        dropdownlist: dropdownList,
                                      ),
                                    );

                                  case "6":
                                    return Padding(
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.h),
                                      child: AdInputField(
                                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                                            value.selectedValueList[index]
                                                .value[0] = newValue.toString();
                                          },
                                          title: data.categoryFieldName,
                                          // controller: TextEditingController(),
                                          keybordType: TextInputType.number),
                                    );

                                  case "1":
                                    return Padding(
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.h),
                                      child: AdInputField(
                                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                                            value.selectedValueList[index]
                                                .value[0] = newValue.toString();

                                            // setState(() {});
                                          },
                                          title: data.categoryFieldName,
                                          // controller: TextEditingController(),
                                          keybordType:
                                              TextInputType.emailAddress),
                                    );

                                  case "3":
                                    return Padding(
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.h),
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          H2semi(text: data.categoryFieldName),
                                          for (int index = 0;
                                              index < data.attributes.length;
                                              index++)
                                            RadioListTile(
                                                title: H3semi(
                                                    text: data.attributes[index]
                                                        .attributeName),
                                                value: index,
                                                groupValue:
                                                    data.categoryFieldId,
                                                onChanged: (newValue) {
                                                  value.updateRadioValue(
                                                      newValue,
                                                      index,
                                                      data.attributes[index]
                                                          .systemValue);
                                                 
                                                }),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    );

                                  case "4":
                                    return SizedBox(
                                      height: 300.h,
                                      width: 1.sw,
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          H2semi(text: data.categoryFieldName),
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: GridView.builder(
                                                gridDelegate:
                                                    SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                                                  childAspectRatio:
                                                      0.45.sw / 24.h,
                                                ),
                                                itemCount:
                                                    data.attributes.length,
                                                itemBuilder:
                                                    (context, attributesIndex) {
                                                  print(
                                                      'check boxes length: ${data.attributes.length}');
                                                  print(
                                                      'checkboxes selected values: ${value.selectedValueList[index].value}');
                                                  return SizedBox(
                                                    width: 0.45.sw,
                                                    child: ExtraCheckBox(
                                                        mainListIndex: index,
                                                        data: data,
                                                        attributeIndex:
                                                            attributesIndex,
                                                        label: data
                                                            .attributes[
                                                                attributesIndex]
                                                            .attributeName,
                                                        isChecked: false),
                                                  );
                                                }),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    );

                                  case "7":
                                    return Container(
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.h),
                                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                      height: 210.h,
                                      width: 350.w,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(3.r),
                                        border: Border.all(
                                          width: 1,
                                          color: ksecondaryColor2,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      child: TextField(
                                        onChanged: (newValue) {
                                          value.selectedValueList[index].value
                                              .insert(0, newValue.toString());
                                        },
                                        maxLines: 15,
                                        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 12.sp,
                                          fontFamily: GoogleFonts.montserrat()
                                              .fontFamily,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                        ),
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          hintText: TextName.describeYourCar,
                                          enabledBorder:
                                              const OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                                          ),
                                          focusedBorder:
                                              const OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );

                                  case "8":
                                    return GestureDetector(
                                      onTap: () async {
                                        await getImages(data: data);
                                        print(data.attributes);
                                      },
                                      child: Container(
                                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                            vertical: 10.h),
                                        width: 350.w,
                                        height: 48.h,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          border: Border.all(
                                            width: 2.w,
                                            color: khelperTextColor,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        child: Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: [
                                            SvgPicture.asset(
                                                'assets/camera.svg'),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              width: 5.w,
                                            ),
                                            H3semi(text: TextName.addPictures),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );

                                  default:
                                    return Center(
                                      child: H2Bold(text: 'No Data'),
                                    );
                                }
                              }),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.h),
                          child: MainButton(
                            isLoading:
                                Provider.of<AddSummary>(context, listen: true)
                                    .isLoading,
                            text: 'Next',
                            onTap: () {
                              context
                                  .read<AddSummary>()
                                  .postAddSummary(value.selectedValueList);
                              
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you are wrapping the whole body with `Consumer` which means, everytime you update the value, its rebuild the widget, but with initail value.

Comment: i have tried to remove consumer and inside the build make a var value = Provider.of<AdsInputField>(context, listen: true); but is also did not work

Comment: `listen= true` it same effect with consumer. every time you call `notifyListener()` it will trigger to rebuild the widget

Comment: i also try 'listen= false' but it was only loading and not moving forward. one other thing when i try to change the values of the drop downs  the screen it not rebuilding and works properly only the problem is with textfields when the keyboard open then the values resets